# How many edges in a k-cycle-free graph?

Tags: graph-theory

From Turan's theorem we know that we can have $O(n^2)$ edges in a triangle-free graph.  The theorem talks about $k$-free graphs, where the graph doesn't contain any cliques of size $k$.

I am looking for an analogy for $k$-cycle-free graphs, that is a graph that doesn't contain a cycle of size $k$ or smaller. All cycles must be of size at least $k+1$.

For $k = 3$, the two definitions are the same (a triangle is a clique and a cycle).
So even help with $k=4,5$ will help me a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: Look up **girth**.

Comment: For a survey of the most important results regarding this problem you may look at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.5167.pdf (especially section 4.1).